# How to get different key value pair keys and values through textBox1.Contains

Tags: c#

So I am working on a game engine with a friend and I am currently working on the collision detection:

Here is the code for moving and looking for detection

```
    private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] text = GameCode.Text.Split(new string[] { System.Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Panel> kvp in objects)
        {
            if (running)
            {
                if (text.Contains("Move " + kvp.Key + " Left"))
                {
                    Point loc = kvp.Value.Location;
                    loc.X = loc.X - 1;
                    kvp.Value.Location = loc;
                }

                if (text.Contains("Move " + kvp.Key + " Right"))
                {
                    Point loc = kvp.Value.Location;
                    loc.X = loc.X + 1;
                    kvp.Value.Location = loc;
                }

                if (text.Contains("Move " + kvp.Key + " Up"))
                {
                    Point loc = kvp.Value.Location;
                    loc.Y = loc.Y - 1;
                    kvp.Value.Location = loc;
                }

                if (text.Contains("Move " + kvp.Key + " Down"))
                {
                    Point loc = kvp.Value.Location;
                    loc.Y = loc.Y + 1;
                    kvp.Value.Location = loc;
                }

                if (text.Contains("Collide " + kvp.Key + " + " + kvp.Key))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Name1: " + kvp.Key + " + Name2: " + kvp.Key);
                }
            }
        }
        //Invalidate();
        DoubleBuffered = false;
    }
```

This is the code for finding two different objects, and then later I will add the collision detection.

```
if (text.Contains("Collide " + kvp.Key + " + " + kvp.Key))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Name1: " + kvp.Key + " + Name2: " + kvp.Key);
}
```

But when I type, Collide obj1 + obj2
Nothing will happen until I change, obj2, to obj1 then it will pop up with obj1 + obj1, but I want to type in Collide obj1 + obj2, then some how detect collision between them, but I don't know how I would achieve this, I have tried many times.

The logic for collision would have been:

```
if (text.Contains("Collide " + kvp.Key + " + " + kvp.Key))
{
    if (kvp.Value.Bounds.IntersectWith(kvp.Value.Bounds))
    {
        //DO something
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess you see results only when you type `Collide obj1 + obj1` is because code is looking for single object (kvp.Key), you might need to change this logic to get a Key(s) for `obj1` and `obj2` and concatenating them.

Comment: But how would I do that? This is the part of the Game Engine that the user will use to actually program the game and make the game.

Say the use wants two objects to move and collide with each other, this is what it should look like:

Move obj1 Right
Move obj2 Left

Collide obj1 + obj2

BTW: the Move part works just fine

Is there a way to check collision for all objects?

Comment: So in each collision, you are expecting both the objects to move, so why don't you consider keeping these keys in temporary variable and display the message ourside foreach loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, inside the loop code is looking for single key, which is why you don't see message popup when you type `Collide obj1 + obj2`

I suggest move this logic outside `foreach` loop, and keep track of object keys when each move is happens.

```
private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] text = GameCode.Text.Split(new string[] { System.Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);

    List<KeyValuePair<string, Panel>> movedObjects = new List<KeyValuePair<string, Panel>>();

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Panel> kvp in objects)
    {
        if (running)
        {
            if (text.Contains("Move " + kvp.Key + " Left"))
            {
                Point loc = kvp.Value.Location;
                loc.X = loc.X - 1;
                kvp.Value.Location = loc;

                movedObjects(kvp); 
            }

            if (text.Contains("Move " + kvp.Key + " Right"))
            {
                Point loc = kvp.Value.Location;
                loc.X = loc.X + 1;
                kvp.Value.Location = loc;
                movedObjects(kvp);
            }

            if (text.Contains("Move " + kvp.Key + " Up"))
            {
                Point loc = kvp.Value.Location;
                loc.Y = loc.Y - 1;
                kvp.Value.Location = loc;
                movedObjects(kvp.Key);
            }

            if (text.Contains("Move " + kvp.Key + " Down"))
            {
                Point loc = kvp.Value.Location;
                loc.Y = loc.Y + 1;
                kvp.Value.Location = loc;
                movedObjects(kvp);
            }
        }

        if(movedObjects.Count() > 1)  // change this logic accordingly when there more than two objects can move.
        {
             MessageBox.Show("Name1: " + movedObjects[0].Key + " + Name2: " + movedObjects[1].Key);

             if (movedObjects[0].Value.Bounds.IntersectWith(movedObjects[1].Value.Bounds))
             {
                 //DO something
             }
        }          
    }
    //Invalidate();
    DoubleBuffered = false;
}
```

Comment: But how do I deal with the collision now, I cant access the bounds of the kvp's value

Comment: Where is that logic performed? if you notice, nothing we changed here except identifying moving objects and displaying a message.

Comment: Moving objects was working before, as I state in a previous comment, i was just trying to check for collision, like if the bounds intersect then a have a message say "Collided" but I want to be able to choose the objects that I want to check for collision

Comment: That's what I was asking in last comment, where is the logic to see see intersection of two objects/points (Logic to determine objects are collided)?

Comment: In that case, in addition to key you need value as well.

Comment: Ok i will try that in the morning

Comment: Ok so it is working, sort of, say I have more than just those two objects looking for collision say I have

`Move obj1 Right
Move obj2 Left


Move obj3 Right
Move obj4 Left

Comment: How would I detect obj3 and 4's collision